# How to plot a distribution plot from multiple files with over 10K lines

Tags: python, bash, gnuplot

I have 10 files each containing around 10,000 files. Each file has 2 columns:

- Time
- Distance Value

Each of these files is centered around a distance value and I need to check the overlap of distribution for all of the **Distance values**. Since these are all float values, it would be futile to calculate the frequency of numbers. Is there some tool that can handle this amount of data and also express the frequency at any distance value?

I am expecting an output of this form: [image]

Please note that the Y-axis is the frequency and not the time from the files.

Comment: I understand you have 10'000 datapoints in 10 files. If you want to calculate a distribution you have to do a sort of binning or bucketing, like for a histogram (easily done with gnuplot). This will give you a distribution curve, i.e. the envelope of your example graph. But what I don't yet understand from your example graph, what are the y-values of the datapoints **inside** the distribution curve? Maybe just a graphical effect, can you comment on this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you assuming the distribution is Gaussian?  If so the answer is minimally:

```
array file[10] = [ "filename.1", "file2.name", "whoeveris.3", ... and so on ]
array mu[10]
array sigma[10]

do for [i=1:10] {
    stats file[i] using 2
    mu[i] = STATS_mean
    sigma[i] = STATS_stddev
}

Gauss(x,mu,sigma) = 1./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp( -(x-mu)**2 / (2*sigma**2) )

plot for [i=1:10] Gauss(x, mu[i], sigma[i]) with lines title file[i]
```

the `stats` command will also calculate error estimates, kurtosis, skew, and and other standard statistical properties of the data in case you want to check whether the distributions really are Gaussian.